# How do you switch focus directly to docked windows in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

As a vim user, I am used to being able to switch the focus to different windows that are side by side with `Ctrl-W [hjkl]`. While Visual Studio offers very nice organization using docked windows, I find that using the `Ctrl-Tab` navigation window disorienting when all I want to do is switch focus to the pane that is to the left or right of the one I'm currently using.

Is there any good way to switch focus in Visual Studio between open windows?

I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 1):

As a (Vs)Vim-mer I am also looking for that essential feature.
Yesterday my VS2013 was behaving strange, but today it is working fine again (don't know what happened), i.e.:

When you have enabled VsVim Handling for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> in

```
Tools/Options/VsVim/Keyboard
```

then Visual Studio behaves like gVim.

If it happens that Visual Studio does not behave as expected (like yesterday ;-)) then you may alternatively use the similar shortcut:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> which is assigned to `Window.NextDocumentWindow`.

This is quite sufficient to switch between both panes. If you hold the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key down and typing <kbd>F6</kbd> another time then it switches to another window, so release the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key when having switched the pane.

You may add / change to another shortcut for this command via the `Environment/Keyboard` Option.